# How to preserve request headers while redirecting using nginx X-Accel-Redirect

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect

My scenario:

**A** sends request to **B** with some custom headers. **Nginx** proxy the request to **B**, where **B** does some logic and sets `X-Accel-Redirect` response header pointing to **C**. Then Nginx redirects request to **C**.

Problem:

**C** does not get custom headers set by **A**. Of course I could rewrite the ones I know using `proxy_set_header` but still have no solution for custom headers.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all headers are preserved automatically. My mistake was that I have tested it with headers containing underscores.